# Microsoft.Crm.DuplicateDetection: Microsoft.Crm.HasDuplicatesPlugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

While qualify Lead to Opportunity we induced a plugin which attaches all lead contacts to opportunity. Basically plugin code will update contact, and insert opportunity id. but there is a duplicate contact rule for contact. So while qualifying, this duplicate detection fires and roll backs even though there is no duplication of contact(NOT satisfies duplicate rule)

Comment: Is it on-premise or on-line?

Comment: on-line. but my issue is solved. Please see my answer below. thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main culprit is "NULL". If any two contact column (used in duplicate detection rule) has NULL value then duplicate detection rule fires and complains as duplicate.

```
FullName    AccountIDname   Lead id
Kilp Foo    NULL             Unknown
Kilp Foo    NULL             Foo LLC
```

---

In the above example, both Account ID name has null. While updating contact, the duplicate detection rule( full name should  not be equal AND accountidname should not be equal) triggers and warns as Duplicate. So to avoid that need to insert account id name at least for one record.

```
FullName    AccountIDname   Lead id
Kilp Foo    FooAccount       Unknown
Kilp Foo    NULL             Foo LLC
```